# Storing preferences in NSUser Defaults to recall later

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsuserdefaults, preferences

Been working on some code streamlining and have realised that it would be really helpful if my app had a preferences system.

Now here's how my code works.

A method runs based upon an integer stored in NSUserDefaults

e.g.

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"scifi1"] == 040){
            [self spaceDown];
        }
        else if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"scifi1"] == 10040){
            [self ctrldown];
            [self spaceDown];
        }
```

Now what I want to do is when I exit the view (via a specific button) is to dump the value of @"scifi1" into a new preference, say for example - an integer named @"savedscifi1"

Now I know how to save integers into NSUserDefaults,

```
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setInteger:VALUEHERE forKey:@"savedscifi1"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
```

However - I'm not sure how I can substiture in the value of scifi1 instead of (in this case) 'VALUEHERE' - can anyone help with this? I feel it's really simple but I can't help but think I'm being a bit thick...sleep deprived and approaching a deadline! I know I can't just call up @"scifi1"but beyond that....??

Comment: `040` is an octal number. It doesn't equal `40`.

Comment: @Jonathan the ascii for space is 0x20 == 32 == 040 so the code looks right

Comment: Actually in this case it doesn't actually matter -these are internally used numbers - not necessarily related to ASCII numbers (though some are, when I started having things like the else if I needed to get creative - but good spot ;) Doesn't have an impact on my question here though :)

Comment: @Nick: Yeah, but nobody actually uses octal numbers, and their presence in code is almost always an error. ;p

Comment: heh funnily I do in a few places, but that's for...complicated reasons lol. Thanks for the help though - it's been a VERY productive day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSInteger value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey: ...];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: value forKey: ...];
```

Comment: Looks like just the job - going to run a quick test before I give it the big ol' green tick but thanks :D

Comment: And there's your tick :) Worked a treat and simple as I expected it should have been! And I think you've actually just given me a prompt to trim a few hundred code lines elsewhere...maybe!